# Recognizing Swift syntax from within coding educational app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking to make an app which allows you to use Swift code within the app - similar to other Swift-based learning education apps to help you learn the language.

Is there a way to use the open source Swift code, for example, in any way to understand the syntax and possibly run the code for typed-in Swift code?

An example of an app I found on the App Store which can do this is called [Sedona](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/sedona-compile-swift-program/id1155835459).

From GitHub [apple/swift/.../Syntax](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/lib/Syntax) there looks to be Swift syntax APIs, presumably for use by IDEs.

- Am I looking in the wrong place?
- Do these types of apps make their own Swift translator?
- Is there some other way this is done?
- Efficiency & optimization is *not* a priority, however would be a benefit.
- It in no way *needs* to include very complex Swift.

*Note: This is for an iOS app only, so Terminal commands would not work.*